# git show-branch using LibGit2Sharp

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

I want to list all the commits on the remote without actually cloning the remote repository locally. Using git, I can do this by the command:

```
git show-branch --more=500 master
```

Do we have a way to do this using LibGit2Sharp as well?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to list all the commits on the remote without actually cloning the remote repository locally. Using git, I can do this by the command:

**[git show-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch)** only operates on a local repository. It doesn't retrieve any commit from the configured remotes.

> Do we have a way to do this using LibGit2Sharp as well?

The following piece of code should emulate `git show-branch`

```
var branch = repository.Branches["master"];

foreach (var commit in branch.Commits)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", commit.Id.ToString(7), commit.MessageShort);
}
```

Comment: @SJM Have this question provided you with any help?